# Is there a way to add arrows for nx. draw in networkx?

Tags: python, pycharm, networkx

I am using networkx in python and am using the nx.draw function which takes in a arrows=True parameter, but the arrows don't seem to show up. When doing this, I am using G=nx.Graph(), but when I use G = nx.DiGraph(), the arrows show up, but the default network shape is lost. Is there a way to preserve the default network layout that comes with nx.draw and also have arrows?

Comment: It would help to see the commands you are using to plot these.  I think this has more to do with the fact that networkx sets the positions of the nodes using an algorithm that has some random inputs, so each time you plot it the positions will be different unless you specify them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to fix the positions yourself, see below for an example using `circular_layout`.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(20, 0.2)
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot of simple graph]
Now `pos` is a dictionary with nodes as keys and coordinates as values. To plot the digraph (with the same node set):

```
G1 = nx.Digraph(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G1, pos=pos)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot digraph]